# Use Google API from flask

Tags: python, flask, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to build a Flask web application that should use some Google APIs (in particular Calendar). Users in the web application are already registered using a custom module, so Google is not used for login.
In my application logged users should associate once their Google account to allow the use of APIs to handle their calendar. I've tried to follow the Google [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python), but it creates a local server which is accessible just locally and does not allows to have a link to embed into a button in a webpage.

I assume to have a structure like this:

```
@app.routes('/allow_calendar')
def allow():
    link = get_googleAuthLink();
    return render_template('page.html', link=link);

@app.routes(/'submit_token', methods=['POST'])
def submit_token():
     ....
     save token received in db
```

With a page like

```
<body>
     <a href={{ link}}>Click here to authorize</a>
     <form action="{{ url_for('submit_token') }}" method="POST">
          <input type="text" id="token">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
</body>
```

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: If it's only accessible locally then that means you're hosting it locally. Did you open ports/launch on the local network?

Comment: It is accessible locally while I develop, but then needs to be moved onto a production server

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to use Google for Login (authentication openId connect) but you do want to access a users google calendar data which means that you will still need to use Google for (Authorization OAuth2)

The sample you are following [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) is intended for use with command line application, this means you are creating installed credentials.

> Complete the steps described in the rest of this page to create a simple Python command-line application that makes requests to the Drive API.

This code will open the web browser window for user authorization on the web server and not on the users machine.  You should be using a web browser client and code designed for use with [web applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server).

Comment: Thanks, however I have a question about it. If I have a web service without a domain name, but just with a static IP I cannot do that, right? Since as URI it seems not accepting an IP address

Comment: As far as i remember you should be able to add a IP address for your redirect uri.  (I havent tried in a while) However the issue you will have is when verifying your application your going to have to have a domain their to host the privacy document.